# How to update nested object? Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update `auction.auctionDescription`. After the request is sent `auction.auctionDescription` is updated, but `auction.auctionImage` is deleted.

```
await Auction.updateOne({_id: id} ,{auction: {'auctionDescription': auctionDescription}})
```

My document looks like the following:

```
_id: ObjectId("...")
user: "..."
animal: {...}
auction: {
  auctionImage: "path/to/image.jpeg"
  auctionDescription: "..."
}
```

Comment: post sample some documents

Comment: How is the object nested? Is it just an object on a document, or is it an array of objects and you're trying to update one of the objects in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you currently have it coded, you are targeting the entire `auction` property and replacing it with the value `{"auctionDescription": auctionDescription}`, which is why it's overwriting the entire existing object.

if you are just trying to update a property on an object on a document, you can use ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to target the specific property on the object you are trying to update, like so:

```
await Auction.updateOne({_id: id}, {"auction.auctionDescription": auctionDescription})
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/L8NxviV I'm trying to update auction.auctionDescription. After the request is sent auction.auctionDescription is updated, but auction.auctionImage is deleted.

Comment: @Casper222 Gotcha, yeah this solution should work for you then, assuming that the image you sent is the `Auction` document. Otherwise, you need to use the top-level document that you are modifying in your `updateOne()` command.